# Postgres Error method org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob() is not implemented

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

When I invoke `createClob` method using connection object as shown below:

```
Clob clob = con.createClob();
```

Following exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob() is not yet implemented.
        at org.postgresql.Driver.notImplemented(Driver.java:659)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob(PgConnection.java:1246)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.createClob(DelegatingConnection.java:868)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.createClob(DelegatingConnection.java:868)
```

I`m using database PostgreSQL 9.6.2 with JDK8 and using commons-dbcp2 connection pool, And added following Postgres dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

In class `org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection`, createClob implementation is as shown below which is throwing the exception:

```
@Override
public Clob createClob() throws SQLException {
    checkClosed();
    throw org.postgresql.Driver.notImplemented(this.getClass(), "createClob()");
}
```

What is the solution or workaround to overcome this issue? Or How can we set CLOB data in *Postgres* queries?

Answer (score 38):

**TL;DR**

- Set `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true` in your  `application.yml` or,
- Set `hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true` in your  `persistence.xml`

It's a known error in JBoss community.

This error appears in former versions and new version with Spring-Boot 2.0.0.RC1 as well and higher.

**Solution**:

1. Update your postgressql-driver with a newer backward compatible version.
2. - Set `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true` in your  `application.yml` or,
   - Set `hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true` in your persistence.xml
3. If it's not working see this trick below:

The solution is to add this line in your property file (or something similar if your are not using spring)

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults= false
```

So, your application.yml should looks like:

```
spring:
    application:
      name: employee-service

    datasource:
      url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_development
      platform: POSTGRESQL
      username: ...
      password: ...

    jpa:
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: create-drop
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
        show_sql: true
      properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false


server:
  port: 8080
```

Reference:

https://o7planning.org/en/11661/spring-boot-jpa-and-spring-transaction-tutorial

[hibernate with c3p0: createClob() is not yet implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46493500/hibernate-with-c3p0-createclob-is-not-yet-implemented)

Thanks to *Binakot* for his comment bellow. I have updated the post.

Comment: If you are using Java-configuration add `org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings#NON_CONTEXTUAL_LOB_CREATION` as key to your JpaPropertyMap and `"true"` as the value.

Comment: You can set `non_contextual_creation` in `application.yml` too (not only in `persistence.xml`): `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true`

Answer (score 4):

put this in to **application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL doesn't really have "CLOB". Just use `setString(String)` or `setObject(...)` with `Types.STRING`.

Answer (score 1):

using spring-boot 2.1.9.RELEASE I added the following and it worked

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
```