# Method org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob() is not yet implemented

Tags: java, spring-boot

How can I solve this error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl.useContextualLobCreation(LobCreatorBuilderImpl.java:113) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl.makeLobCreatorBuilder(LobCreatorBuilderImpl.java:54) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.<init>(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:271) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:114) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:861) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:888) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) [spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388) [spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) [spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) [spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) [spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) [spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) [spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) [spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) [spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) [spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1085) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:858) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at com.divergent.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]



Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob() is not yet implemented.
    at org.postgresql.Driver.notImplemented(Driver.java:683) ~[postgresql-42.2.1.jar:42.2.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob(PgConnection.java:1252) ~[postgresql-42.2.1.jar:42.2.1]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hibernate with c3p0: createClob() is not yet implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46493500/hibernate-with-c3p0-createclob-is-not-yet-implemented)

Comment: "hibernate with c32p0..." doesn't mention Spring Boot, although answers do

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65094862/how-to-resolve-method-org-postgresql-jdbc-pgconnection-createblob-is-not-yet/65703651#65703651; createBlob/Clob is currently implemented for Postgres 42.3.0

Answer (score 234):

Add this property in your application.properties :

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

Reference :

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12007#issuecomment-369388646

Comment: Didn't work with Spring Boot 2.1.6.  It's possible there was a [regression](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/2572#issuecomment-494356864).

Comment: Worked for 2.1.9 RELEASE.

Comment: Didn't work with Spring Boot 2.4.4. Finally I've found that is a hibernates bug, so 1) I've deleted upper configuration + 2) upgrated Hibernate version from `5.2.10.Final` to `5.4.2.Final`. Than started to work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55732898/how-to-resolve-org-postgresql-jdbc-pgconnection-createclob-is-not-yet-implemen

Answer (score 46):

This is an issue of `Hibernate`, as a workaround, you can use the following flag. Then set up the following config in your properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

For **Spring boot 2.x.x** this flag simply disable contextual LOB creation, but if you really want to know the properly answer check **UPDATE V1**.

**UPDATED V1**

This was a Hibernate [issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12368).
If you use Spring Boot latest version from `2.0.x` until `2.1.x`
includes `Hibernate 5.3.10.final` you can take a look [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/2.1.6.RELEASE) but this issue was fixed on `Hibernate version` **5.4.0.CR1** then you need to add that dependency or if it is possible the latest version:

**For Gradle:**

```
compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.2.Final')
```

**For Maven:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

**UPDATED V2 "SPRING BOOT 2.2.0.M(1-4)"**

In addition `Spring boot v2.2.0.Mx` includes now `Hibernate v5.4.x` then this issue was fixed for these versions.

Comment: Cool I added more information about it and updated supporting of versions for spring boot. @ShekhFirozAlam

Comment: In Spring Boot 2.2.1.RELEASE, still got the problem. 
mohammad hejazi's answer worked.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54288767/4766882

Answer (score 33):

I had the similar issue.
I followed this solution and it worked for me

http://vkuzel.blogspot.com/2016/03/spring-boot-jpa-hibernate-atomikos.html

```
# Disable feature detection by this undocumented parameter. Check the org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServiceImpl.configure method for more details.
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false

# Because detection is disabled you have to set correct dialect by hand.
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
```

Comment: This worked for me.  However, I used `spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL` instead of the dialect.

Answer (score 19):

Solved by using following Yaml configuration:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        jdbc:
          lob:
            non_contextual_creation: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
```

Answer (score 13):

Solved by adding **hibernate.properties** with

```
hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

Other solutions with `application.properties` didn't work. This can be also done via XML hibernate.cfg.xml

Spring Boot version: 2.0.2.RELEASE

Comment: are you sure you started with spring.jpa ? this works fine in 2.0.3 for me

Comment: @KalpeshSoni sorry, can't answer. Its a spring-boot project with business dependency of another project, in which persistence stuff is defined. Hard to reproduce this setup to figure it out.

Answer (score 8):

```
spring:      
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        temp:
          use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
        jdbc:
          lob:
            non_contextual_creation: true
```

with

```
use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
```

or

```
non_contextual_creation: true
```

two items work fine

Comment: Why should we use the above configs? what do they do?

Answer (score 4):

Faced the same problem with Spring Boot version: 2.1.x.RELEASE too. 
it worked with:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

Comment: I did, but it was not working. Is there the other way?

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this stuff for a day.

- Spring boot version `2.2.5`
- Postgres: `42.2.10`
- Version of Postgres on server: `PostgreSQL 11.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.9.3, 64-bit`

I was using Spring JPA data with Hibernate configuration. Using sessionFactory.

Hibernate configuration:

```
@Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
@Primary
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(assetHealthDataSource);
    sessionFactoryBean.setMappingDirectoryLocations(new Resource[]{new ClassPathResource("mappings")});
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

    return sessionFactoryBean;
}
```

Hibernate Properties:

```
private final Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.setProperty(
            "hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty(
            "hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation", "true");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty(
            "hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults", "false");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty(
            "hibernate.show_sql", environment.getProperty("assetHealthDataSource.hibernate.showSQL"));
    hibernateProperties.setProperty(
            "hibernate.format_sql", environment.getProperty("assetHealthDataSource.hibernate.formatSQL"));
    hibernateProperties.setProperty(
            "hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session", "false");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty(
            "hibernate.hibernate.connection.release_mode", "auto");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty(
            "hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize", "3");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty(
            "hibernate.default_schema", "MY_SCHEMA");

    return hibernateProperties;
}
```

But everything was not working properly. Willing to see any suggestion that can help to solve this out. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: ak, it was solved. I would like to confirm that this problem would not occur in Springboot 2.2.5 and Hibernate 4.2.14 Final, I got the error because there is an Oracle driver in the application, maybe it led to conflict. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone searching for a Grails answer (3.3 and up), @Ashutosh's answer worked for me but what caught me out is in your application.yml file, you omit the `spring.jpa.properties` prefix. Add it to the hibernate section, where you're likely to have your dialect specified:

```
hibernate:
    dialect: <your dialect>
    jdbc:
        lob:
            non_contextual_creation: true
    temp:
        use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
```