# How to resolve "Method org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createBlob() is not yet implemented"

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have seen posts on how to resolve `org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob() is not yet implemented` and I have applied `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true` as suggested by those posts on the createClob() issue. My issue is I am getting the `is not yet implemented` message but in reference to the create**B**lob() method in particular.

How do I resolve this for the create**B**lob() method in particular?

Hibernate Core 5.4.20

Postgre 42.2.18

Spring Boot 2.3.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a byte array as specified at https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/binary-data.html. That page also discusses how to use Large Object (BLOB) functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The method createBlob is just about to be implemented in Postgres 42.3.0:
https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/pull/1272/files

https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/projects/2#card-11520125