# Spring boot application error with connect PostgreSQL database

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I just generated new project on https://start.spring.io/, added

1. Web
2. Security
3. JPA
4. PostgreSQL

then I have Description:

```
Failed to auto-configure a DataSource: 'spring.datasource.url' is not specified and no embedded datasource could be auto-configured.
```

So I added

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://10.1.2.5/vlex

spring.datasource.username=myUser
spring.datasource.password=myPassword

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

into application.properties and now I have:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob() is not yet implemented.
```

I cannot overcome this problem and stuck here. Is there any way to use PostgreSQL 9.6 in Spring Boot application? I haven't edited anything but application.properties

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding property:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

or if you have specific `hibernate.xml` you can set same property there to `true`

There is issue on github: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12007

Similar issue: [Postgres Error method org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob() is not implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43905119/postgres-error-method-org-postgresql-jdbc-pgconnection-createclob-is-not-imple?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 3):

For PostgreSQL you need to set this two property

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Comment: Works but this one below also works no idea which answer should I accept

Comment: Are you sure that `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect` is required ? It should not I think.

Comment: Even: spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false
 is enough

Comment: Ahh Okay I see. I faced this issue sometimes ago. This two line saved me. Now I know only one line would be enough. Thanks guys

Comment: @Michu93 spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false - probably does much more then property I mentioned in my answer, so in case you have only exception you stated in question, I would've used specific property for this problem