# Spring Boot - JPA Hibernate not creating tables automatically?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have this code in my `application.properties` file:

```
# Spring DataSource
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.sql.init.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root

# JPA-Hibernate
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43905119/postgres-error-method-org-postgresql-jdbc-pgconnection-createclob-is-not-imple
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

# Optimization for POSTGRES queries
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
```

As you can see I have the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` line added but the tables are still not being created by the JPA. I have to manually create them in order for the project to compile. What is wrong?

Comment: maybe you use some keywords which reserved by jpa in you entities as fields.

Answer (score 5):

u can use `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` and check u are using @Table(name="table_name") top on  entity class.
it may help

Answer (score 2):

There are several possible causes:

```
Your entity classes are in the same or in a sub-package relative one where you have you class with @EnableAutoConfiguration. If not then your spring app does not see them and hence will not create anything in db

Your application.properties must be in src/main/resources folder.
```

try adding @ComponentScan("package which contains entity classes, configurations and services")

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have added @Entity annotation to your model classes. Also, make sure that model classes are in the desired package.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have to do:

1- Add `@Entity` annotation to every class you want to see as table

2- Add these lines in your application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=false 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

Answer (score 0):

Check these annotations:
1- @Table( name:    ), @ Entity  on you class.
2- @Column(name: ), on each field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in the application.properties file it was work for me.

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE


spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
```

And also use this annotation above the entity class.

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name=" give the name of the table you want ")
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I created a new model, and one of the fields had a column name that was a reserved SQL keyword (e.g. "start", "end", "table", etc.) The table creation would fail due to a syntax error, but the application still started "successfully" for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your imports are from `javax.persistence` and not `jakarta.persistence`. Took me a while to solve this problem in a project where I was importing `jakarta.persistence.Entity` as well as other annotations.  Once I switched all annotation imports to `javax.persistence` it all worked.

Answer (score 0):

i faced this issue so in application.properties, i replace

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl.auto=update
```

with

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

additionally i added(optional)

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.jpa.database = MYSQL
```