# Spring JDBC failing - Method org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob() is not yet implemented

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-jdbc

I am working on an application that uses Spring JDBC and postgresql-42.4.24.jar. While executing an update query, the batch application fails with the below exception.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob() is not yet implemented.
    at org.postgresql.Driver.notImplemented(Driver.java:699) ~[postgresql-42.2.24.jar:42.2.24]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob(PgConnection.java:1344) ~[postgresql-42.2.24.jar:42.2.24]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.createClob(DelegatingConnection.java:868) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.createClob(DelegatingConnection.java:868) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.TemporaryLobCreator.setClobAsString(TemporaryLobCreator.java:101) ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$1.setValues(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:238) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:914) ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:909) ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:644) ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
```

**Note** I am not using Spring JPA or Hibernate for this application. Please help me resolve this issue.

The batch application should run as expected completing all update queries. Since this is a legacy application, it doesn't use Spring JPA or Hibernate.

Comment: It seems that createClob() is not being implemented in postgresql for now. Is there any other Spring-jdbc version that doesn't invoke the createClob() method.
                                                                                                                                                                                       
 @Override
  public Clob createClob() throws SQLException {
    checkClosed();
    throw org.postgresql.Driver.notImplemented(this.getClass(), "createClob()");
  }

Comment: While debugging, the application is trying to update the BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT table. This in turn is invoking the createClob() method from postgresql.jar via TemporaryLobCreator.java class in Spring-jdbc-4.0.5.RELEASE-sources.jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring-JDBC framework depends on the creation of DefaultLobHandler which is invoking postgresql to implement the createClob() method.

In order to prevent this, please assign the property *createTemporaryLob* within defaultLobHandler to false. This should resolve the issue for any EJB related batch applications.

Comment: <bean id="defaultLobHandler" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.DefaultLobHandler">
        <property name="createTemporaryLob" value="false" />
    </bean>

Answer (score 0):

Checking your stack, it looks that Spring is being used.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58211993/15823178), and this [website](https://alexpask.com/spring-boot-createclob-error/) you need to set the parameter.

Comment: yes but I am not using any Hibernate or Spring JPA. It is an EJB application which uses some imports from spring framework.

Comment: Could you send some snippets of your code?

Comment: my apologies but its company code so I can't share that here.